# scanner class in java

Tags: java

Hey I'm trying to compile the following piece of code to basically read stuff from a file but it refuses to work. it gives me an java.io.FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION error at line4. help would be appreciated.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;


 public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    File fin = new File ("matrix1.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fin);
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
       String line = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: My first guess would be that it couldn't find the file..

Comment: make sure the file exists in the same directory as where your class is

Comment: yes, it is in the same directory.

Comment: You need to catch the Exception being thrown. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the absolute path to the file, like

`c:\\java\\matrix1.txt` or `/home/user/java/matrix1.txt`

=== OOPS

You need to catch the Exception that's being thrown. Here's a couple options:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fin = new File ("matrix1.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fin);
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
       String line = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);
       }
    }
 }
```

OR

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;


 public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       File fin = new File ("matrix1.txt");

       Scanner sc = null;
       try {
           scanner = new Scanner(fin);
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("File does not exist...");
          return;
       }
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
       String line = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @pst I have the second one compiling. "Works on my machine!"

Comment: @pst So I'm not sure why it compiled to start with. It really didn't. The post is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure matrix1.txt is in your src folder if you're using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IDE such as Netbeans/Eclipse, you need to put the file to be read in the project folder. This is usually 1 level above the src folder.

A good alternative in case you can't find the folder is to try and **create** a file. That way, you know where the file was created and you can place the file you want to read in that same folder.